# Nginx upstream to external URL hang

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I'm trying to proxy pass to an external URL from like below, it's hang.
curl -v http://test.local => this will hang forever.

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name localhost test.local;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
upstream frontend {
  server     www.google.com  fail_timeout=10s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying upstream servers by domain name you need to include a [resolver](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive